# Python BeautifulSoup is not printing the data

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Python BeautifulSoup is not printing the data

```
import urllib3
import certifi
from urllib3 import PoolManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

manager=PoolManager(num_pools=3,cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',ca_certs=certifi.where())

page=manager.request('GET',"https://app.tipotapp.com/docs")

print(page.status)

print(page.headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
```

-

```
python --version 
Python 3.7.0a2 

pip3 install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade 
Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 
in c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\li‌​b\site-packages
```

Comment: C:\Users\Naveen>python --version                                                     Python 3.7.0a2

C:\Users\Naveen>pip3 install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade         Requirement already up-to-date: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\naveen\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: Please format your code and state your question

Comment: next time put question in question's body - title should be only short description.

Comment: you have to create better question. Put what you get and what you expected. Don't expect that we will run code to see this.

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to this site. Going forward I'll follow the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTML` is in `page.data`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.data, 'html.parser')
```